# python concatenation in cycle partitioning

Tags: python, concatenation

I understand that I can only concatenate things of similar types, but I'm really confused as to why the following are of different types.

this a part of my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gurobipy as GRB

def solveOptCyclePartition(diGraph):
# Create the Optimization Model
   try:
     m = GRB.Model("ctrlModel")
     linkWeights = {}
     for (u,v) in sorted(diGraph.edges(data=False)):
        linkWeights[(u,v)] = diGraph[u][v]['weight']

     #Create variables
     e = m.addVars(sorted(diGraph.edges(data=False)),lb=0.0,ub=1.0, 
         obj=linkWeights , name="e")

     # Add the objective function  
     m.setObjective( (e.prod(linkWeights)), GRB.MAXIMIZE)

     #Add Constraint: One output edge from each node
     m.addConstrs( (e.sum(i,'*') == 1 for i in nx.nodes(diGraph)), "outDegree")

     #Add Constraint: One input edge from each node
     m.addConstrs( (e.sum('*',i) == 1 for i in nx.nodes(diGraph)), "inDegree")

     # Compute optimal solution
     m.optimize()

     # Print solution
     if m.status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
        objOptimalVal = m.getAttr('objVal') 
        solution = m.getAttr('x', e)
        for (u,v) in sorted(diGraph.edges(data=False)):
            if solution[u,v] > 0:
                print('%s -> %s: %g' % (u, v, solution[u,v]))
        return objOptimalVal , solution

 except:
    print('Error reported')
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------        

#def main():

# Network Adjacency Matrix
A = np.matrix([[0,0,0],
       [1,0,0],
       [1,0,1]])
G = nx.DiGraph()
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)

# Check to see if connected
if nx.is_connected(G) == False:
   print('The graph is not connected and has unaccessible nodes')
   sys.exit(0)

# Nodes and Edge Lists
nodes = nx.nodes(G)
N = len(nodes)
edgeList = nx.to_edgelist(G)

# M Actuator nodes are selected randomly fron N nodes 
M = 1;
augNodes = range(N,N+M)
actuatorNodes = sorted(list(np.random.permutation(np.arange(N))[:M]))
actuatorEdges = [(i,actuatorNodes[N-i],{'weight':1}) for i in augNodes ]

# Augmented edges lists and augmented graph 
augEdgeList = (edgeList + actuatorEdges +  
    [(i,j,{'weight':0}) for i in nodes for j in augNodes] +
    [(i,i,{'weight':0}) for i in nodes+augNodes if (i,i,{'weight':1}) not in edgeList])

Gprim = nx.DiGraph()
Gprim = nx.from_edgelist(augEdgeList,Gprim)

# Poljak Algorithm: Perform maximum weight cycle partitioning on 
# augmented graph and return the optimal solution
objOptimalVal, solution = solveOptCyclePartition(Gprim)

plt.draw()
# Evaluate the solution


#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    main()
```

I'm trying to solve cycle partitioning to find among all the partitions the one that encompasses the maximum number of edges with unit weight and satisfies the
following constraint. but i get this error:

```
*** TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "range") to list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the full stack trace it's hard to be sure exactly where this error is occurring, but I believe that it is happening on the following line:

```
[(i,i,{'weight':0}) for i in nodes+augNodes if (i,i,{'weight':1}) not in edgeList])
```

The particular section to pay attention to is `nodes+augNodes`.

[The `nodes` variable contains the return value from calling `networkx.nodes()` which returns a list according to the documentation.](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html) `augNodes` on the other hand is being set to a range on the following line:

```
augNodes = range(N,N+M)
```

Since you can't append a range to a list, you're getting the `TypeError` that you see.